# Indesign: How to fix last line of text to bottom

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, page-layout, formatting

is there any way in indesign to break a paragraph at a given point and fix the last line to the bottom in the same way it happens with the shift key+tab command for right indent tab? I always resorted to making two text fields but always thought there must've been a smarter way to do so. Thank you! [image]

Comment: As a rather hacky solution, you could use *footnotes* to achieve this. Don't know if I would recommend it though. Just tried it and it's more convoluted than just having two text frames.

Comment: Are you aware that you can make a paragraph jump to the next frame using *Keep Options*? So if you set up your document with two text frames on each page you can control everything with styles (provided that you never have a page *without* a paragraph in the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, but probably not possible, because vertical alignment is a text box property, not a paragraph style property.

You can improvise this in a way, by using a vertical justify on the text box and manually increasing the 'Space before' value of the final paragraph.